# php javascript query structure

Tags: javascript, php, structure

I just want to get an idea if i'm on the right track with regards to loading my page dynamically. Basically i have a home page where i want combo box to load from my mysql database. Currently I have a onload="load_home(); function in my body tag. This calls a function in my js file which in turn calls my load_home.php file. The load_home.php creates my combo box in html and returns it. The js then uses
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText; 
line to add the combo box to my page.

Is this a long version of what I'm trying to achieve??? Would I be better just returning a resultSet to the javascript and using json or something to build the html for my page. I just want to know before I do any more coding. The  selected item in the first combo will in turn lod the information in another combo(makes and models). I'm using js so that this can be done without a page reload.

Thanks in advance peeps.

EDIT.................

JavaScript file:

```
function load_home() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "load_home.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

HTML file:

```
</head>
<body onload="load_home();">

<p><b>Welcome to my page</b></p>
<div id="data">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what i'm doing each time i want to change an element of a page. Seems like a lot of functions with XMLHttpRequest()'s to achive what I want. The load_home.php will generat a table in html from a mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

My new Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#makeCombo").load("PHP/load_home.php");

});
```

My php

```
<?php  
//connect to database
include('db_connect.php');  

$sql = "SELECT MAKES FROM makes_and_models GROUP BY MAKES ORDER BY MAKES ASC";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
//counter to control table rows -- will print 5 columns before moving to a new row
$count = 0;
echo '<select id="makeCombo">';
echo '<option value="Select Make">Select Make</option>';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    //if counter is 0 start new row

    echo '<option value="' . $row['MAKES'] . '">' . $row['MAKES'] . '</option>';


} 


echo '</select>';
//close db connection
mysql_close();

?>
```

Am I on right track by setting up combo with php this way?

Comment: @rajat-jain Any comments?